# OnEdit Script to create a new spreadsheet file, then grant access to the user who triggered it

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, permissions

My script contains an installable onEdit trigger, causing DriveApp to copy a file, rename it, fill some values automatically, once a certain cell in the main spreadsheet is set to a specific value.

Multiple users will be using and editing the main spreadsheet at the same time.

I now want to give edit access to the newly created file to JUST the user who caused the onEdit trigger to create it.

I'm not sure if this is possible. Here's what I tried (as part of a bigger onEdit function).

```
// Give User Permission for new file
let activeuser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
DriveApp.getFileById(internalID).addEditor(activeuser)
```

I also tried the same thing with "getEffectiveUser() but both will result in empty strings...

grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using the onEdit simple trigger because simple triggers have some restrictions.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions

They cannot access services that require authorization. We are trying to access DriveApp which requires authorization. So, this approach won't work.

Alternative:

1. Create a separate method which you can name anything. For eg, I've named it onSpreadsheetEdit. Define same functionality in it which you had initially.

   ```
   function onSpreadsheetEdit() {
      var fileId = <your_file_id>;
      var activeUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
      DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).addEditor(activeUser);
    }
   ```
2. Create an installable edit trigger instead of a simple trigger.

[image]

The onSpreadsheetEdit method will always run with the account with which you have created the trigger.

Note: I am assuming that the Session Active User will be the one who has edited the sheet because as soon as the edit happens, the function onSpreadsheetEdit function runs.

Comment: So like this? 

// Give User Permission for new Internal
    let activeuser = e.user.email;
    DriveApp.getFileById(internalID).addEditor(activeuser)


This resulted in an error upon testing & edit rights were not added.

Comment: Correct. What is the error, can you check it from the logs ?

Comment: The error: "Exception: Invalid Argument: permission.value".

I am testing this with a non-GSuite account. I've done some research and appearantly, what I want to do is impossible?

Comment: Is there a way to give edit permission not by email, but by username? maybe that would be a workaround.

Comment: I think this is not possible using onEdit. I have another alternative. Will update the answer in a minute.

Comment: Done, just updated the answer. Please try this approach.

Comment: Thanks for editing, but this is already exactly what I have (as I mentioned in my question, I am using an installable trigger already). It's unfortunately not working & I think it has to do with the testing account not being a GSuite account.

Comment: Oh, I see. Apologies, I missed reading that. Can you try with a G Suite or Gmail account to see if it works? To make sure it's just the domain which is causing the issue.

Comment: Tested with both, a GSuite and a foreign email account, both times permission was not granted & I get an error notification (still "Exception: Invalid Argument: permission.value"). I tried with the dev account & it works, even sends an auto email to me that a spreadsheet has been shared with me.

Comment: Can you try adding the argument e in onSpreadsheetEdit method? And then access the user who made the edit using e.user.email. Not fully sure if this will work but it's worth a try.

Comment: Tried this already after your initial answer (before you edited it) & to no avail. It's weird. There has to be a way....